# How can I add a static background behind a UITableView programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a TableViewController and would like to have a static picture as a background, which doesn't scroll along.

The way that everyone recommends using

```
 [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundPattern.png"]]
```

doesn't work as it will

1.) move along and 
2.) put the background pattern in every cell

I know how to do it in a XIB file (namely adding another layer underneath the TableView) but how do I do it programmatically from the TableViewController?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[myTblViewController.view insertSubview:myImageView belowSubview:myTblViewController.tableView];
```

That should work.

If it turns out that `tableView` is not a direct subview of the table view controller's main view, you can try:

```
[[myTblViewController.tableView superview] insertSubview:myImageView belowSubview:myTblViewController.tableView]; //Edited superview should be all lower case
```

Comment: UITableViewController / UIViewController doesn't have an insertSubview:belowSubview method...